# Wordpress Child Category Display All Posts

Tags: posts, categories, children

I am creating a Wordpress page where all my posts in the child categories of team are displayed in a grid. I got this working with the below code. The formatting and general layout is great however it only shows the 5 most recent posts in the child category instead of all of them. In my Wordpress account I have 7 posts which should be displaying. How should I retrieve the posts so it displays them all.

```
                <ul class="faces">

 <?php
$categories = get_categories( 'child_of=2' );  
foreach  ( $categories as $category ) {

    echo '<div class="grid-row"><h2>'.$category->name.'</h2></div>';

    $cat_posts = get_posts( 'cat='.$category->term_id );
    $end = count( $cat_posts ) - 1;
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $cat_posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        $face = get_field( 'face' );
        $name = get_field( 'fullname' );

        if ( $i % 6 === 0 ) {
            echo '<div class="grid-row">';
        }
      echo '<div class="obj">';

        echo wp_get_attachment_image($face)
            . '<div class="name">'.$name.'</div>';

        echo '</div>';
                if ( $i % 6 === 5 ) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
               $i++;
    }
}?>
    </ul>
```

//css

```
div.grid-row {
    width: 100%;

   height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.obj{
float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.faces{
    width: 1000px;

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

REVISED TO POST BELOW:
[image]

REV FOR POST BELOW:

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories( 'child_of=2' );  
foreach  ( $categories as $category ) {

    echo '<div class="grid-row"><h2>'.$category->name.'</h2></div>';
    $args1 = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cat='.$category->term_id );
    $cat_posts = get_posts( $args1 );
    $end = count( $cat_posts ) - 1;
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $cat_posts as $post ) {
    $post_category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if($post_category->cat_name == $category->name){
        setup_postdata( $post );
        $face = get_field( 'face' );
        $name = get_field( 'fullname' );

        if ( $i % 6 === 0 ) {
            echo '<div class="grid-row">';
        }
      echo '<div class="obj">';

       echo '<div class="faceThumb">';
       echo wp_get_attachment_image($face);
       echo '</div>';
          echo '<div class="name">';
          echo $name;
          echo '</div>';

        echo '</div>';
                if ( $i % 6 === 5 ) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        }
               $i++;

    }
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the arguments you can supply to get_posts is posts_per_page. If you don't include this, then it will default to your Pages Show at Most setting on the Reading page of your settings. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_posts-not-pull-all-posts-unless-numberposts-in-query. Yes, I know the forum thread is 2 years old, but it confirms the suspicion that I had after reading http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts and the Source File listed at the bottom of that page.

Comment: how would I add that into this line : $cat_posts = get_posts( 'cat='.$category->term_id );

Comment: Look at the example on the codex page. They create an array of arguments and then call $posts_array = get_posts( $args); In your case, it would be $cat_posts = get_posts($args);

Comment: if you look now it is getting all of them however not by child category. 2013 has 7 posts and 2012 only has 1 post. Why are both showing up in each? I added: $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cat='.$category->term_id );
    $cat_posts = get_posts( $args );

Comment: Because you have to specify the parent category. I ran into this problem when I was trying to have category pages display only the categories directly underneath them and not their grandchildren.  I wrote a snippet for it at http://rightthewriter.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/smart-subcategory-display/

Comment: I looked through that and am a tad confused do you mind explaining how it works so i can figure out how to implement it.

Comment: Because I was thinking about grouping categories and how I did it. In actually there is a simpler method. In your foreach ( $cat_posts as $post ) loop put $post_category = get_the_category($post->ID); Then compare the $post_category->cat_name to the $category->name if they aren't equal don't show them. Read about Get the Category  in the Codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

Comment: Can you look at my revised code above because now I'm not seeing anything for either. Thank You.

Comment: That's why.  get_the_category returns an array. So the line that is comparing the two category names should be  if($post_category[0]->cat_name == $category->name)

Comment: still seeing nothing

Comment: When you say seeing nothing are you getting a totally blank screen?  If you are that means there is a PHP error going on.

Answer (score 0):

Can be a lot simpler. I don't know what `get_field` is, I think is your custom function... but why don't use standard custom fields and post thumbnail future? Anyway

```
$categories = get_categories( 'child_of=3' ); 

foreach  ( $categories as $category ) {
  $i = -1;
  echo '<div class="grid-row"><h2>' . $category->name . '</h2></div>';
  $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cat' => $category->term_id );
  $cat_posts = new WP_Query($args);
  if ( $cat_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $cat_posts->have_posts() ) :
    $i++;
    $cat_posts->the_post();
    $face = get_field( 'face' );
    $name = get_field( 'fullname' );
    if ( $i % 6 == 0 ) echo '<div class="grid-row">';
    echo '<div class="obj">';
    echo '<div class="faceThumb">';
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($face);
    echo '</div><div class="name">' . $name . '</div></div>';
    if ( ($i % 6 == 5) || $i == ($cat_posts->post_count - 1) ) echo '</div>';
  endwhile; endif;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: it no longer shows the same for both so it works from that standpoint however it no longer wraps every 6th

Comment: I've edited the code, now it should works. I've just changed `$i = 0;`  in `$i = -1;` in the second line.

Comment: nope still getting 7 all in a row.

Comment: Ok, now works. There was an error even in you code, when all posts were not a multiple of 6, last `div` of a row was not closed. Now it's all ok. This was not a WP related problem... however is solved.